# Add a regular table inside a responsive/mobile page

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm wondering what options are available to me here.

I currently have a client with a site that is using media queries to make it responsive.

I have also included this piece of code to allow for full width scaling..

`<meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport">`

My issue is that there is a table on one of the pages (its a Wordpress site). The client wishes for this table to be viewed normally (as if you were viewing a table on a desktop).

This would mean smaller text etc (the equivalent of looking at table on your mobile in desktop view).

Is there a way of doing this? I cant give it a set `width` like 980px for example as this will only push beyond the width of the entire page on a mobile.

My thinking was to change `<meta content="width=device-width" name="viewport">` to something like `<meta content="width=980" name="viewport">` JUST for that page id, this would mean the entire page would look like a desktop site. Im not entirely this will work either as there may be rules in the CSS of the headers and other parts that might react differently.

Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried the table-layout or scale down the font-size ?

Comment: I havent tried scaling down the font-size actually. Im not sure how table-layout would help, but that said I dont fully understand that property. I would assume a fixed table layout wouldnt help?

Comment: I will try the font size scaling and report back , if it works you can answer the question if you like.

Comment: oki, let me know if it is usefull :)

Comment: Do you have an URL to see the code and dimensions of the actual site?

Comment: Ok that worked, I reduced image sizes , font sizes and anything else included. Thank you, feel free to answer the question